# Mac OS VPN Connection Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, vpn, system-configuration

I want to create code which will create new connection with L2TP Protocol .

below is my code.

I didn't find any error but code run successfully and create new network but it's not showing data which i passes e.g username.

```
- (IBAction)connectVPN_Cliced:(NSButton *)sender{

VPNServiceConfig *config = [[VPNServiceConfig alloc]init];
config.username = @"username";
config.password = @"password";
config.endpointPrefix = @"Server IP end prefix";
config.endpointSuffix = @"Server IP end endpointSuffix";
config.sharedSecret = @"sharedkey";
config.name = @"L2TP By Mac Application";
config.endpoint = @"Server IP";
config.type = 1;

[self setupVPN:config];
}


- (AuthorizationRef) getAuth {
    AuthorizationRef auth = NULL;
    OSStatus status;
    status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,     [self flags], &auth);
    if (status == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully obtained Authorization reference");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Could not obtain Authorization reference");
        exit(101);
    }
    return auth;
}

- (AuthorizationFlags) flags {
    return kAuthorizationFlagDefaults    |
kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights       |
kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize;
}
- (void)setupVPN:(VPNServiceConfig *)vpnConfig {
        // Obtaining permission to modify network settings
        AuthorizationRef auth = [self getAuth];
        SCPreferencesRef prefs =     SCPreferencesCreateWithAuthorization(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("macVPN"), NULL, auth);

        SCPreferencesUnlock(prefs);
    //-------- This is i tried by me to add data but it's not working ------ Start //
        SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("Type"), CFSTR("PPP"));
        SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("SubType"), CFSTR("L2TP"));
        SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("AuthName"), CFSTR("username"));
        SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("AuthPassword"), CFSTR("password"));
        SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("CommRemoteAddress"), CFSTR("server ip"));

        NSData *pppData = [@"0000" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    CFDataRef ref = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, pppData.bytes, pppData.length);

    // CFPropertyListFormat

    CFPropertyListRef propertyRef = CFPropertyListCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, ref, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers, nil,nil);

    Boolean isValidData = CFPropertyListIsValid(propertyRef, kCFPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0);

    SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, CFSTR("AuthPassword"), propertyRef);

    //-------- This is i tried by me to add data but it's not working ------ End //

    // Making sure other process cannot make configuration modifications
    // by obtaining a system-wide lock over the system preferences.
    if (SCPreferencesLock(prefs, TRUE)) {
        NSLog(@"Gained superhuman rights.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sorry, without superuser privileges I won't be able to add any VPN interfaces.");
        return;
    }
    // If everything will work out fin
    [self createService:vpnConfig usingPreferencesRef:prefs];

    // We're done, other processes may modify the system configuration again

    return;
}


- (void) createService:(VPNServiceConfig *)config usingPreferencesRef:(SCPreferencesRef)prefs {
    NSLog(@"Creating new %@ Service using %@", config.humanType, config);
    // These variables will hold references to our new interfaces

    SCNetworkInterfaceRef bottomInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(kSCNetworkInterfaceIPv4,kSCNetworkInterfaceTypeL2TP);

    SCNetworkInterfaceRef topInterface = SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithInterface(bottomInterface, kSCNetworkInterfaceTypePPP);
        // Creating a new, fresh VPN service in memory using the interface we already created

        SCNetworkServiceRef service = SCNetworkServiceCreate(prefs, topInterface);
    // That service is to have a name
        SCNetworkServiceSetName(service, (__bridge CFStringRef)config.name);
    // And we also woould like to know the internal ID of this service

        NSString *serviceID = (__bridge NSString *)(SCNetworkServiceGetServiceID(service));
        // It will be used to find the correct passwords in the system keychain
        //config.serviceID = serviceID;
        [config setServiceID:serviceID];

        // Interestingly enough, the interface variables in itself are now worthless
        // We used them to create the service and that's it, we cannot modify them any more.
        CFRelease(topInterface);
        CFRelease(bottomInterface);
        topInterface = NULL;
        bottomInterface = NULL;

        topInterface = SCNetworkServiceGetInterface(service);

    // Let's apply all configuration to the PPTP interface
    // Specifically, the servername, account username and password
        if (SCNetworkInterfaceSetConfiguration(topInterface, config.L2TPIPSecConfig)) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully configured PPP interface of service %@", config.name);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: Could not configure PPP interface for service %@", config.name);
            return;
        }

        if (SCNetworkInterfaceSetExtendedConfiguration(topInterface, kSCEntNetIPSec, config.L2TPIPSecConfig)) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully configured IPSec on PPP interface for service %@", config.name);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: Could not configure PPTP on PPP interface for service %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());

            //return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Adding default protocols (DNS, etc.) to service %@...", config.name);

        if (!SCNetworkServiceEstablishDefaultConfiguration(service)) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not establish a default service configuration for %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());
        return;
        }


        NSLog(@"Fetching set of all available network services...");


        SCNetworkSetRef networkSet = SCNetworkSetCopyCurrent(prefs);


         if (!networkSet) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Could not fetch current network set when creating %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());
    return;
    }
    if (!SCNetworkSetAddService (networkSet, service)) {
        if (SCError() == 1005) {
            NSLog(@"Skipping VPN Service %@ because it already exists.", config.humanType);
            return;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: Could not add new VPN service %@ to current network set. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());
            return;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Fetching IPv4 protocol of service %@....", config.name);

    SCNetworkProtocolRef protocol = SCNetworkServiceCopyProtocol(service, kSCNetworkProtocolTypeIPv4);



    if (!protocol) {

        NSLog(@"Error: Could not fetch IPv4 protocol of %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());

        return;
    }

     NSLog(@"Configuring IPv4 protocol of service %@...", config.name);

    if (!SCNetworkProtocolSetConfiguration(protocol, config.L2TPIPSecConfig)) {

        NSLog(@"Error: Could not configure IPv4 protocol of %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());

        return;

    }



    NSLog(@"Commiting all changes including service %@...", config.name);

    if (!SCPreferencesCommitChanges(prefs)) {

        NSLog(@"Error: Could not commit preferences with service %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());

        return;

     }
    NSLog(@"Preparing to add Keychain items for service %@...", config.name);

    // The password and the shared secret are not stored directly in the System Preferences .plist file

    // Instead we put them into the KeyChain. I know we're creating new items each time you run this application

    // But this actually is the same behaviour you get using the official System Preferences Network Pane

    [VPNKeychain createPasswordKeyChainItem:config.name forService:serviceID withAccount:config.username andPassword:config.password];

    [VPNKeychain createSharedSecretKeyChainItem:config.name forService:serviceID withPassword:config.sharedSecret];


    if (!SCPreferencesApplyChanges(prefs)) {

        NSLog(@"Error: Could not apply changes with service %@. %s (Code %i)", config.name, SCErrorString(SCError()), SCError());

        return;

    }
    NSLog(@"Successfully created %@ VPN %@ with ID %@", config.humanType, config.name, serviceID);



    return;
}
```

I tried this : 
[how to set up a vpn connection programmatically in MAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022250/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-connection-programmatically-in-mac/28940873?noredirect=1#comment46137607_28940873)

Update : 
Code I used to auto connect to vpn server

```
SCNetworkConnectionRef  connetionRef =  SCNetworkConnectionCreateWithServiceID(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)(newServiceId), myCallBack, &callBackContext);
SCNetworkConnectionStart(connetionRef, config.L2TPPPPConfig, FALSE);
```

Comment: have you got the solution? i am also facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes I have solved the issue but I am able to create L2tp Over IPSec Connection not the only L2TP.

Comment: Thanks Bro, All data show. Now i want to auto connect network. Do you now how this will achieve?

Comment: Please check out my edits for code

Comment: i have done with Scrip follow the Link http://superuser.com/questions/358513/start-configured-vpn-from-command-line-osx/358663#358663

Comment: How to check Network Already Exist. i facing the issue everytime create the new network connection. Do you have any idea?

Comment: how to get root privilege? Because helpertool not give root privilege. Please help me out?

Comment: Give me sometime I will post answer for this here with the solution..how I achieve this.

Comment: @malave Soni  Thanks for your precious time, i have some urgency please take some time for posting answer related to root privilege A.S.A.P.

Comment: @SawanCool what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: i am facing in L2TP SharedSecret key when we edit manually entered SSKey then it work. From code it not work

Comment: which class you are using to save SSKey?

Comment: i copy the  VPNKeychain code to Helpertool class, and use the code                               - (void) createSharedSecretKeyChainItemAuthorization:(NSData *)authData lable:(NSString*)label forService:(NSString*)service withPassword:(NSString*)password withReply:(void(^)(NSError * error))reply ;

Comment: I have done the same thing in my code and it's working here

Comment: Through this code all data set perfectly but connection error come. The Issue in SSkey because when we go to authentication setting and again enter SSkey then press connect this time successfully connect.

Comment: Ohh sorry my mistake i just pass the wrong value in the config.sharedSecret. Thanks For your precious time, Again Thanks (Y)